# SQL Subquery Determination

Tags: oracle11g

Please help with the error ORA-01427. I am using spring3-JPA2 and the following query throws out ORA-01427.

I need to understand which part of the query is treated as a subquery. Or is it the view code which is throwing it? Please note it happens only for a couple of records we test with.

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_GET_GROUP_QUEUE taskgroup
WHERE taskgroup.COMPONENT_ID=?1
  AND taskgroup.ROLE_CODE=?2
  AND ((taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE LIKE ?3
        OR taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE IS NULL))
  AND taskgroup.SOEID=?4
  AND ROWNUM=1
```

Comment: I can't see any problems with this query. I think the problem is somewhere in the view definition

Comment: Is taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE LIKE ?3 OR taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE IS NULL treatedasa subquery?we get the following error

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: "taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE LIKE ?3 OR taskgroup.WORK_ITEM_TYPE IS NULL" are just two conditions. It's not a suquery. I suppose the subquery is somewhere in the view definition (VW_GET_GROUP_QUEUE)

Comment: thank you..any way to determine which subquery in the view definition can be failing..hibernate error is too generic

Comment: post the view definition

Comment: Hi Multisync,can you post ur email id plz?